# bmp image to matrix (2d array) in c

Tags: c, arrays, image, bitmap, bmp

I need to put a bmp (RGB 24 bit) image into a 2D array, using the C language.
I have written some functions, but those functions work only with square images.
I have created this structure to store the pixels:

```
typedef struct{
int red;
int green;
int blue;
}pixel;
```

I have also created two int extern values Y and X to store height and width of the image.
This is the code (I omitted the setWidthHeight and CreateNewImage functions because I'm sure they work)

```
int X, Y;

int bitmapin(FILE* fp,/* int height, int width, */ pixel** img1){
    long n;
    int t;
    fseek(fp, 10, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&t, 1, 4, fp);            //reads the offset and puts it in t
    fseek(fp, t, SEEK_SET);         
    int i, p, e;
    e=4-((X*3)%4);
    if (e==4) {
        e=0;
    }
    for (i=Y-1; i>=0; i-- ) {
        for (p=0; p<X; p++) {
            n=fread(&img1[i][p].blue, 1, 1, fp);
            if (n!=1) {
                return 29;
            }
            n=fread(&img1[i][p].green, 1, 1, fp);
            if (n!=1) {
                return 30;
            }
            n=fread(&img1[i][p].red, 1, 1, fp);
            if (n!=1) {
                return 31;
            }
        }
        fseek(fp, e, SEEK_CUR);
    }
    return 0;
}

pixel** make2Dpixelarray(/*int y, int x*/){
    pixel** theArray;
    theArray=(pixel**) malloc(X*sizeof(pixel*));
    for (int i=0; i<X; i++) {
        theArray[i]=(pixel*) malloc(Y*sizeof(pixel));
    }
    return theArray;
}



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   FILE* fp;
    fp=fopen("/Users/admin/desktop/Immagine5.bmp", "r");
    if (fp==NULL) {
        return 20;
    }
    setWidthHeight(fp);               //Puts X=width and Y=height, it works
    pixel** img1=make2Dpixelarray();  //Creates 2D pixel array and get the memory for it
    bitmapin(fp, img1);               //this function should put the values of RGB pixel into the matrix
    CreateNewImage(fp, img1);        //This function creates a new image.
    return 0;
}
```

When the image is square there are no problems but when:

- height>width: I get the error "BAD_ACCESS..." when i try to read the first pixel in bitmapin()
- width>height: The first line of pixel is OK. But the left side is a kind of copy of the right side with much more blue and very little green.

Could someone help me solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your x and y swapped when you fread values into your array. I think. It's not like I've tested this out or anything. WAY too lazy for that.

```
for (i=Y-1; i>=0; i-- ) {
    for (p=0; p<X; p++) {
        n=fread(&img1[i][p].blue
```

`i` walks through `Y` and `p` walks through `X`.

When you malloc it, you set it up for img[x][y]

```
theArray=(pixel**) malloc(X*sizeof(pixel*));
for (int i=0; i<X; i++) {
    theArray[i]=(pixel*) malloc(Y*sizeof(pixel));
```

General advice: Stay away from globals, for this I'd pass in variables as you have commented out.   Name your variables better than `t` and `e`.  What are your return 29,30,31 values? Try an enum or #defines with names. (and you just ignore the return value afterwards)

The biggest reason this bug wasn't apparent is probably the naming scheme. i and p? Come on, pass in sizeX, and sizeY, and have x and y as your worker variables.   If the context wasn't bitmapin(), the variables should even be bitmapSizeX.  Naming is important yo.

Comment: Thank You very much! You solved my problem! You are right I should have named variables better.